# Why Google analytics website is not working on my android browser?

Tags: google-analytics, android

Everytime when I open analytics.google.com on my android phone, it shows me error.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a **customer support** question. [Why customer support questions are off-topic here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745) .